# Login Forms Display on Checkout Page When Already Logged In

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

My client has a site that was built by another developer. When on the CHECKOUT page, the pay shows the LOGIN and REGISTER forms, even when the user is already logged in. Logging in again does nothing and the system doesn't recognize the action.

I have searched a bunch but can’t find anything related to this issue or how to fix it. Any thoughts on what page I should be editing, or what code I'm looking for (and how to modify it)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Probably hard coded a login form but didn't wrap it in `if( !is_user_loggedin() ) :`.  So you'll need to find where that login form is added and how and then wrap it in that conditional check.  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/